# Assembler task : translations

Tags: assembly

[image: Here given fragments of the source code and their translation]

Why.L21 (which is longer than .L27) is faster than .L27?

Why flag -funroll-loops speeds up loop1 but doesn't speed up loop2?

Comment: because the first case was not properly optimized... it can be shortened to `return a[n-1] * x * x * x * x;`, throwing away the whole loop.  = I mean, your question makes little sense, the compiler must in first place produce correct code, whether it is close to optimal solution is secondary, depends how big was the source, how well it was written, which options and compiler were used, etc... you didn't even specify which compiler and which options were used, so it's completely impossible to say why that particular machine code emerged as result, but even with details it would be difficult.

Comment: maybe I'm wrong about that shortening, am I? Will have to check, the gcc 7.3 doesn't find it, and I guess it's rather mistake on my side, than being that superhuman so early in a day... oh, clang finds it, so it's really just gcc failing to recognize the simplified formula. Interesting. https://godbolt.org/g/p2MGHs  (I didn't mention the test for `n` is of course needed, to skip the `for` completely for `(n <= 0)`).

Comment: What hardware has a speed difference?  IvyBridge and later should be able to run the rolled-up version of `loop1` at 1 `imul` per clock (3 ALU uops thanks to `mov`-elimination), so on recent hardware `-funroll-loops` should only help if that helps gcc omit useless `imul` instructions for loop iterations other than the last one, or optimize away the loop entirely.

Comment: Yup, `-funroll-loops` just helps gcc with the missed-optimization.  Although this code appears to be from an ancient version of gcc, like gcc4.1 https://godbolt.org/g/eDe8FX.  Even gcc4.9 sinks the `imul` out of the loop, but even gcc8.1 still does every load.  (Auto-vectorizing with SSE2 or AVX2, though!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, about your question... the first loop doesn't have dependency inside the loop, i.e. each iteration of loop is independent and can be calculated ASAP (actually all except the last iteration can be just thrown away, because they don't affect return value at all).

The second loop for each iteration depends on previous result, so the CPU has to wait with each next `imul` until the previous result is ready. The `imul` on modern x86 has still throughput about 1.0 I guess, but the latency may be above 1.0 and not sure what the dependency will do, depends completely on your target CPU platform, which you didn't specify. (somebody like Peter Cordes can surely answer this for particular modern Intel micro architectures, or you can read yourself Agner's tables, but as you didn't specify target architecture, I don't see point in making any particular real world example, for me this general chit-chat level is enough)

For example on 80386 I guess the second loop would be faster, because it has less instructions, and 80386 was still quite "simple" inside, with `imul` taking several clocks in either case. On latest Intel CPUs the dependency will probably just so-so skew it in favour of first one, but not much, as `imul` is reasonably fast today.

Anyway, this is nice example how sorting out your algorithm first, and tuning that, will give you the biggest performance gain, as the first loop is not a real loop, and writing it as simple formula will make the code even faster.

Curiously enough, I tried in godbolt explorer, what modern compilers do about it, and gcc does some quite convoluted thing to read through each array member, or what exactly does that wall of instructions do (too lazy to check in debugger), while clang compiler does see through it and produces the simplified formula instead: https://godbolt.org/g/p2MGHs

P.S. the first loop can be simplified down to:

```
int loop1_fix(int *a, int x, int n) {
    if (0 < n) return a[n-1]*x*x*x*x;
    else return x*x*x;
}
```

Comment: According to http://agner.org/optimize/, `imul r32, r/m32` is 3c latency, 1c throughput on Intel as far back as Core2, and on Ryzen. (So the dependent loop is ~3x slower than the independent loop, for large `n`).  On AMD before Ryzen, it's 4c latency, 2c throughput, only a factor of 2 difference between a throughput vs. latency bottleneck.